# ¿Cómo hago para que node no compile todo el pug cada vez que alguien se conecta?

Tags: nodejs, express, pug

Soy nuevo en la programación web y me interesa aprender algunos conceptos.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con node, express, pug y mssql.
Estoy generando los html con pug.

La pregunta específica es: yo voy a tener generalmente un html estático, que me imagino que no es necesario que se compile cada vez que un usuario accede al sitio, y otra parte dinámica que entiendo eso sí tiene que compilarse.

¿Cómo hago esto? ¿O estoy errado? Es usando blocks? 
Desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola!

Creo que te estás liando un poquillo y mezclando algunos conceptos.

Si estás usando un MVC tradicional deberías tener un directorio con las vistas .pug.

Estos archivos llevan tanto el html estático como las posibles variables que vayas a renderizar en su interior.

Pero siempre debes renderizar (lo que llamas compilar) la vista a la hora de realizar la respuesta de tu aplicación.

Es por medio de los bloques condicionales cuando mostraras contenido dinámico o simplemente devolverás el html sin más. Pero siempre lo renderizas en la respuesta.

¡Espero que te sirva de ayuda! =)

Comment: Ok! Queria saber si SIEMPRE habia que renderizar todo, o si el html estatico podia quedar estático sin mas... Gracias!

Comment: Si estás usando archivos .pug tienes que renderizarlos siempre. Sobre todo porque pug tiene su propia sintaxis que convierte en html. Y así tienes todos en el mismo formato. =)

Comment: Pero los archivos pug no estarán en su aplicación, allí solo tendrá el html generado